# jquery выполнение команд во время выполнения ajax запроса

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пытаюсь вывести на страницу информацию что ajax запрос в процессе выполнения, но не могу понять как это сделать. Пытался вот так:

```
    var html = $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        $(id).fadeIn(10); 
      },
      type: "GET",
      url: "getcontent.php",
      data: "json=1&element="+el+"&dependence="+dep,
      async: false,
      success: function(){
          $('#mask, .window').hide();
      }
     }).responseText;
```

Что я делаю не так?
Но если поставить async: true, то структура json не успеет запонится! И соответственно ajax запрос делается бесполезным!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так Вам надо выполнять асинхронный запрос, иначе зачем Вам вообще ajax?

Вам не нужен никакой `beforeSend` — просто делаете запрос и сразу же выводите сообщение о том, что запрос выполняется. Как только запрос выполнен, убираете это сообщение.

Про структуру json, которая не успеет заполниться, ничего не понял. Но если в Вашем коде просто сделать `async = true`, то это будет что-то совсем не то. Надо написать нормальный асинхронный код.

Вам нужна примерно такая логика:

```
$.get("getcontent.php", { "json": "1", "element": el, "dependence": dep },
   function(data){
     // Проверить, не случилось ли ошибки
     // Убрать сообщение, что запрос выполняется
     // Обработать полученные данные (например, записать текст в нужный элемент)

   }, "json");
// Вывести сообщение «запрос обрабатывается»
```

*Очень-очень рекомендую ознакомиться с [документацией jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).*